# Problem with minimum element of an array in windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, default

I am learning how to create simple .NET applications. In this application I'm adding numbers in array of integers from `TextBox`, and display the biggest and smallest number from this array in the `ListBox`. The problem is that when I'm finding minimum number using `Min` method it always gives me 0, however `Max` method works just fine

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // ...

        int[] array = new int[100];
        int counter = 0;
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(txtInsertNumber.Text);
            }
            counter++;
        }

        private void btnShowMinMax_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            int max = array.Max();
            int min = array.Min();

            int maxIndex = Array.IndexOf(array, max);
            int minIndex = Array.IndexOf(array, min);

            listBox1.Items.Add(array[maxIndex] + " " + array[minIndex]);
        }
    }
```

[image: Screen of application interface]

Comment: Use `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)` The `counter` is never  `++` because its not in the `for .. loop` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array `int[] array = new int[100];` is initialized with 100 integers with the default value of 0. That's why the minimum value is 0.

The solution would be to have an array of `Nullable<int>` to differenciate "no value" `null` from real values. Example:

```
int[] a = new int[50];
Console.WriteLine(a.Min()); // prints "0"

Nullable<int>[] b = new Nullable<int>[100];
Console.WriteLine(b.Min()); // prints ""
```

Comment: @aleisher welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to market as answer if it solves your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use  `List<int>` with a predefined size.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int>(10);
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);

        var min = list.Min(); //  will be 1
        var max = list.Max(); // will be 2 
    }
```